# Unable to open the remote html file in JetBrains client

Tags: python, django, pycharm, windows-subsystem-for-linux, jetbrains-ide

I'm using JetBrains Client 2023.3 RC. I have Django HTML templates in my project. When I try to open them, the JetBrains client displays the message:

> "Unable to open the remote file".

[image]

Other files open without problems.
I have to open these HTML files in other editors, but sometimes I need to debug them. I don’t know if this is important or not, but for remote development I use WSL, which has Ubuntu 22.04 installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug with the latest version of the Gateway Client. UNMARK your `templates` directory as Template Folder and that should fix the problem for the time being until the bug is fixed.